# How to push arrays into a nested array?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to push multiple arrays into the column section.

```
  .then(body => {
    this.options = {
      padding: {
        left: 100,
        right: 100
      },
      data: {
        columns: [
        ],
      }
     }
    }
```

I have an array that contains a list of arrays.

```
let new_array = {['test1', 2,3,5,6], ['test2', 5,3,9,6], ['test3', 1,2,5,2]}
```

I tried to write a function to push the arrays into columns, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.  I'm not sure how to push things into columns.

```
function populateColumn(new_array) {
  for (var i in new_array) {
    this.options['data']['columns'].push(new_array[i]);
  }
}
```

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: You are getting `new_array` as an argument. Should it be `new_array[i]` instead of `this.new_array[i]`?

Comment: Also, note that `new_array` is not an array, it is an object.

Answer (score 0):

If you want flat array, use 
`this.options['data']['columns'].push(...new_array[i]);` instead of `this.options['data']['columns'].push(new_array[i]);`

or use `this.options['data']['columns'] = this.options['data']['columns'].concat(new_array[i])`

Yes, and `new_array` should be an array, not object.

Comment: what does the .. in front of new_array do?

Comment: It is spread operator: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

```js
const options = {
  data: {
    columns: []
  }
};

const new_array = [
  ["test1", 2, 3, 5, 6],
  ["test2", 5, 3, 9, 6],
  ["test3", 1, 2, 5, 2]
];

function populateColumn(array) {
  options.data.columns = [...array];  
}

populateColumn(new_array);

console.log('options.data.columns:', options.data.columns);
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have an invalid object, you might want to update new_array from

```
let new_array = {['test1', 2,3,5,6], ['test2', 5,3,9,6], ['test3', 1,2,5,2]}
```

to

```
let new_array = [['test1', 2,3,5,6], ['test2', 5,3,9,6], ['test3', 1,2,5,2]]
```

Working demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qjwfcq